# Destroy a specific session PHP

Tags: php, session

An short example :

How can I ( = admin ) destroy a session of someone else ?

I know the session_id.

I tryed something like this :

```
$old_session = session_id(); // my session admin.

session_id('id_session');
session_destroy();

session_id($old_session);
```

Didnt work.

Comment: To clarify: A user is logged in to your system on a different computer from yours and you want to stop their session. Is this correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can delete the session's file (if you're storing sessions in the filesystem) with something like:

```
$file = session_save_path()."sess_".session_id();
unlink($file);
```

Comment: assuming you are using file storage for your session

Comment: and if you're not using file storage??

Comment: @Anthony if you're using Database storage, delete the entry from the respective table

Comment: why would it be in a table in the first place? the session stores a cookie somewhere on the user's PC. how do you invalidate that cookies?

Comment: @Anthony the cookie is simply a "key" that refers to data stored on the server. Destroy the server-side data and the cookie points nowhere.

Comment: makes sense, but in which table is the server-side data for a session stored (if not in a table of my own creation)? :/

Comment: @Anthony the default session storage for PHP is "file", and that is saved in the folder specified by the `session.save_path` pgp.ini setting (the default is usually `/tmp`). If a database is used, it means there's some custom code that's setting it. Look for `session_set_save_handler()` occurrences in the code if you want to find out more about the implementation you're dealing with.

Comment: @periklis ty very much sir.

Comment: shouldn't it be `$file = session_save_path()."/sess_".session_id();`??

Answer (score -2):

To destroy a session you use

```
unset($_SESSION['variable']);
```

For your case maybe :

```
session_regenerate_id(true);
```

to regenerate the id

Comment: He's trying to destroy another user's session, not his own.