# how to delete/destroy/unset a specific php session

Tags: php, session

I need to delete/destroy/unset a specific session

```
$('#btnlogout').on('click', function(){
        $.post('pro.php', {fn: 'btn_logout'}, function(data){
            location.href = location.href;
        });
});
```

**pro.php**

```
function btn_logout(){
    //$_SESSION['id'] = 5; //this works
    unset($_SESSION['id']);  // doesn't work
    destroy_session();  // doesn't work
}
```

`echo $_SESSION['id']` on main page always gives me a value

here - [How do I destroy a specific session variable in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28602173/) `unset($_SESSION['id'])` is accepted answer, but I tried so many times - doesn't work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Destroy a specific session PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16818302/destroy-a-specific-session-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unset method itself does the trick but until the page is refreshed it echo the last instance. you can try this

```
session_start();

if(isset(($_SESSION['id'])){
    unset($_SESSION['id']);
    die();
    header ('Location: index.php'); //optional line, any other page can be used
}
```

Comment: tried - doesn't work - btw - why `if (isset...` - echo session gives a value - meaning - it is set ?

Comment: Yes its optional to use isset but not a good practice because if session is not set what the use of unsetting it. Also on which page you are echoing the session?

Comment: using ajax call. Changing tha value of the session using the same way - works. But unset the session - doesn't

Comment: is this your full unset session page ?? or there is something else on page?

Comment: see my update, pls

Comment: Okk sorry my bad my code didn't worked because Session needs to be started on every page where session variable is used..i edited my code you can check now

Comment: hmm... `pro.php` is included in main page - and included AFTER `session_start` on main page. Anyway I started it again on `'pro.php` an now it works, but how to explain ?

Comment: See you need to use session_start() on every page where $_SESSION is used ...using it after or before including a page will not work. if you need more help you can add me on discord or something